# how to convert python code in to function

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python by my self. i write this code. I try to convert this python code in function by using main. I do know how to do it. can someone help me with it. I did try for more than 3 hrs. now my mind is stop working. I will really appreciated your help.

isExit = 0

count = 0

total_int = 0

while True:

```
total_int = 0

count = 0

print ("\n")

print ("1) Credit Card Payoff Summary")

print ("2) Credit Card Payoff Details")

print ("3) Exit ")

choice = (int)(input("Enter your choice - "))

if(choice == 1):

    balance = (float)(input("Enter your credit card balance - "))

    apr = (float)(input("Enter Annual Percentage Rate - "))

    print ("1) Interest on current balance + 1% of current balance.")

    print ("2) 2% of current balance.")

    select = (int)(input("Select your choice - "))

    if(select == 1):

        if(balance <= 0 or apr <= 0) : #checking if balance or APR is 0 or not

            print ("Interest cannot be calculated as balance or APR is 0.")

        else :

            while (balance > 0) :

                m_interest = float(balance) * (apr/ 1200)

                min_month_pay = m_interest + (0.01 * balance)

                if (min_month_pay < 15):

                    min_month_pay = 15

                principal_paid = min_month_pay - m_interest

                balance = balance - principal_paid

                total_int += m_interest

                count += 1

            years = (float)(count / 12)

            print ("Years required to payoff card : ", round(years, 2)) #round() is used to format the float number upto 2 decimal place.

            print ("Total interest paid : ", round(total_int,2))

elif(select == 2):

    if(balance <= 0 or apr <= 0) :

        print ("Interest cannot be calculated as balance or APR is 0.")

    else :

        while (balance > 0) :

            m_interest = float(balance) * (apr/ 1200)

            min_month_pay = 0.02 * balance

            if (min_month_pay < 15):

                min_month_pay = 15

            principal_paid = min_month_pay - m_interest

            balance = balance - principal_paid

            total_int += m_interest

            count += 1

        years = (float)(count / 12)

        print ("Years required to payoff card : ", round(years, 2))

        print ("Total interest paid : ", round(total_int, 2))

else :

    print ("Invalid selection.")
    if(choice == 2):
        balance = (float)(input("Enter your credit card balance - "))

        apr = (float)(input("Enter Annual Percentage Rate - "))

    print ("1) Interest on current balance + 1% of current balance.")

    print ("2) 2% of current balance.")

    select = (int)(input("Select your choice - "))

    if(select == 1):

        if(balance <= 0 or apr <= 0) :

            print ("Interest cannot be calculated as balance or APR is 0.")

        else :

            print ("Month Min. Int. Princ. Rem. Pay. Paid Paid Bal.") #headers of the detail

            while (balance > 0) :

                m_interest = float(balance) * (apr/ 1200)

                min_month_pay = m_interest + (0.01 * balance)

                if (min_month_pay < 15):

                    min_month_pay = 15

                principal_paid = min_month_pay - m_interest

                balance = balance - principal_paid

                total_int += m_interest

                count += 1

                print (count, " ", round(min_month_pay, 2), " ", round(m_interest, 2), " ", round(principal_paid, 2), " ", round(balance, 2)) #This will print the detail line by line

            years = (float)(count / 12)

            print ("Years required to payoff card : ", round(years, 2))

            print ("Total interest paid : ", round(total_int, 2))

if(select == 2):

    if(balance <= 0 or apr <= 0) :

        print ("Interest cannot be calculated as balance or APR is 0.")

    else :

        print ("Month Min. Int. Princ. Rem. Pay. Paid Paid Bal.")

        while (balance > 0) :

            m_interest = float(balance) * (apr/ 1200)

            min_month_pay = 0.02 * balance

            if (min_month_pay < 15):

                min_month_pay = 15

            principal_paid = min_month_pay - m_interest

            balance = balance - principal_paid

            total_int += m_interest

            count += 1

            print (count, " ", round(min_month_pay, 2), " ", round(m_interest, 2), " ", round(principal_paid, 2), " ", round(balance, 2))

        years = (float)(count / 12)

        print ("Years required to payoff card : ", round(years, 2))

        print ("Total interest paid : ", round(total_int, 2))

else :

        print ("Invalid selection.")

if (choice == 3):

        print ("Application is terminating now.")

        isExit = 1

else:

        print ("Invalid Choice.")

if(isExit):

    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this statement

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

select all your code `ctrl+a`, press `tab` to indent it, then put the statement above in the beginning of your code

**Explanation**

When the Python interpreter reads a python file, the file is either 1 of 2 things, it's either a program with a main method or the file is a module that some other main file imports. This attribute is stored in a variable named `__name__` . If the  value of `__name__` is equal to `'__main__'` then it indicates to the interpreter this file is intended to be run as a program (main). Otherwise this file is likely being imported from some other program.

Although you don't actually need this statement as far as I know. If you just run a bunch of code sequentially without using any main declaration then that's fine too. Most people put it at the bottom of their file and then call the functions that are declared above it like this:

```
def func1():
    print("function 1")
    some_string = "hello"
    return some_string

def func2():
    print("function 2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("here is the main method where you can call functions above")
   results = func1()
   func2()
```

Comment: I try that too. can you please provide me a details about it.